# after I install flutter and Android, I cant to fix the following issue:

Tags: android, flutter, dart-pub

[!] HTTP Host Availability

```
1 HTTP host "https://cocoapods.org/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host: Connection terminated during handshake

2 HTTP host "https://maven.google.com/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host:Connection terminated during handshake

3 HTTP host "https://pub.dev/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host: Connection terminated during handshake

4 HTTP host "https://cloud.google.com/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host: Connection terminated during handshake
```

I reinstall this version in my window  again, flutter_windows_3.7.11-stable.zip but the issue was not fixed,